# How can I do an impex import for the below script?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I'm facing the below concern while importing. Could anyone help me to resolve the problem?.

INSERT_UPDATE CxConfig;code[unique=true];basesites(uid);consenttemplates(pk)
;SAPYMKT_PERS_CSIN_CONF;csin;"#% impex.exportItemsFlexibleSearch( "" select CONCAT(',#2,',CONCAT({con.pk},',' )) from {consenttemplate as con join basesite as bs on {bs.pk} = {con.basesite}} where {id} = 'SAPYMKT_PERS' and {bs.uid} = 'csin'"");"

throwing the below error:
INSERT_UPDATE CxConfig;code[unique=true];basesites(uid);consenttemplates(pk)
",,,,pk has wrong format: '#% impex.exportItemsFlexibleSearch( "" select CONCAT('':For input string: ""#% impex.exportItemsFlexibleSearch( "" select CONCAT('""";SAPYMKT_PERS_CSIN_CONF;csin;"#% impex.exportItemsFlexibleSearch( "" select CONCAT(',#2,',CONCAT({con.pk},',' )) from {consenttemplate as con join basesite as bs on {bs.pk} = {con.basesite}} where {id} = 'SAPYMKT_PERS' and {bs.uid} = 'csin'"");"

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be imported, because it becomes at export script when you include "impex.exportItemsFlexibleSearch" in the second line.

If you were planning to export data, you can do it in:

- HAC: Console > ImpEx Export
- Backoffice: System > Tools > Export